# Android Adding seekbar in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a SeekBar programatically in an android application.

This is my code:

```
SeekBar seekbar = new SeekBar(this);
    seekbar.setMax(6);
    seekbar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    LinearLayout linearLayout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    linearLayout.addView(seekBar);
```

However, when the method addView is called, I get this exception

```
06-21 22:11:26.286: E/AndroidRuntime(13354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.T4J_OAuth.activities/com.T4J_OAuth.activities.ExampleTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.T4J_OAuth.activities/com.T4J_OAuth.activities.feedbackActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Am I doing something wrong with the code. Just to note, the activity where I am trying to add the seekBar is part of a parent activity which contains to Tabs. Therefore this activity is one of the tabs.

This is my feedbackActivity class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.feedback_form)

    String unitName = "Unit:" + ExampleTabActivity.unitName;
    final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textViewToChange.setText(unitName);

    String lectureName = "Lecture:" + ExampleTabActivity.lectureName;
    final TextView textViewToChange2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textViewToChange2.setText(lectureName);



    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ExampleTabActivity.subsections);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    SeekBar seekbar = new SeekBar(this);
    seekbar.setMax(6);
    seekbar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));*/
    LinearLayout linearLayout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    linearLayout.addView(seekBar);
}
```

This part of the TabActivity which creates the tabs

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;

    Intent newIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, feedbackActivity.class);

    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("structured")
            .setIndicator(createTabView(this, "Structured"))
            .setContent(newIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    Intent newIntent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, feedbackNLActivity.class);

    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("nl")
            .setIndicator(createTabView(this, "Natural Language"))
            .setContent(newIntent2);

    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

This is the complete stack trace of the error

```
    06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.T4J_OAuth.activities/com.T4J_OAuth.activities.ExampleTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.T4J_OAuth.activities/com.T4J_OAuth.activities.feedbackActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.T4J_OAuth.activities/com.T4J_OAuth.activities.feedbackActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1656)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:656)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at com.T4J_OAuth.activities.ExampleTabActivity.onCreate(ExampleTabActivity.java:354)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    ... 11 more
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at com.T4J_OAuth.activities.feedbackActivity.onCreate(feedbackActivity.java:85)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
06-21 22:21:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(14643):    ... 20 more
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:overScrollMode="always" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true" 
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Unit Name: Data Structurs"
    android:textSize="20dp" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Lecture Name: Queues"
    android:textSize="15dp" />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have set the content view before adding this piece of code? could you please add more code and also the complete stack trace of the error :) or at least tell us at what line do you get the null pointer exception.. :)

Comment: please provide complete concrete unction of feedbackActivity and layout XML

Comment: Try to set the max seek value after the setLayoutParams call.. the setLayoutParams() method should be the first one to be called when you create a View.. maybe that is the problem..

Comment: @Cata I tried it and it behaves the same. It was not the problem unfortunately

Comment: Do you even have a `LinearLayout` with _id_ `R.id.linearLayout1` at `R.layout.feedback_form`?

Comment: @K-ballo Yes I have a LinearLayout. I added the xml file in the question, you can take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: I removed the TabActivity, therefore calling directly the feedback Activity, but the problem still persists. Any further ideas?

Comment: Do you know at which line do you get the null pointer? I can't figure out that from the stack trace..

Comment: I am currently debugging it step by step. I will return to you in some minutes. I added a setId method to the seek bar, and now it seems that it is going further with the methods since it gave an exception at PhoneWindow.getDecor() but now it passed that method. I will tell you again..Thankyou very much for your time @Cata

Comment: I got it again..this is the last line which ran before the exception related methods
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1830 @Cata

but Eclipse did not have any source code for that I copied this from the stack trace

Comment: @Cata Solved it and stupid mistake..I had commented a button in the xml file which I was calling from the activity to set a listener. Thank you all